# Orbeon autocomplete display JSON response

Tags: json, autocomplete, orbeon

I'm trying to fill the autocomplete field in Orbeon (version 2016.1) with suggestions which I receive as a JSON.
The JSON I get looks like:

```
{"status":"success","code":200,"data":{"streets":[{"name":"Street One","id":"1"},{"name":"Street Two","id":"2"},{"name":"Street Three","id":"3"}]}}
```

I know that the Resource URI should point to my web service (could that URI, or the arguments I need to send, be encoded?), but I don't know how  the Items, Label and Value fields should be configured in this case (the label would be name from the json and value should point to the code from the json, of course).
I referred to https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/submission-json.html but haven't exactly managed to get what I'm trying to.

Can someone help?
Thanks in advance.

Masa

Answer (score 0):

In particular, with your specific JSON, the corresponding XML will look as follows. In general, see the section [Seeing the converted XML](https://doc.orbeon.com/xforms/submission-json.html#seeing-the-converted-xml) for how you can create a form in Form Builder that allows you to see what the converted XML is for any JSON.

```
<json type="object">
   <status>success</status>
   <code type="number">200</code>
   <data type="object">
      <streets type="array">
         <_ type="object">
            <name>Street One</name>
            <id>1</id>
         </_>
         <_ type="object">
            <name>Street Two</name>
            <id>2</id>
         </_>
         <_ type="object">
            <name>Street Three</name>
            <id>3</id>
         </_>
      </streets>
   </data>
</json>
```